# Get MySQL ID to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a database which holds profiles.
I get these profiles through an sql statement and encode them to json, and print them with javascript to make the user able to filter in these profiles in the frontend.

In a nutshell need to get the primary key (ID) from an sql statement through json and into a script, so i can use the id to create individual profile pages who get their own URL.

The last part of my MYSQL file looks like this

```
$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
```

The script which prints the result from the query is

```
function makeTable(data){
var getUID = "<?php $row['UID'] ?>";
var tbl_body = "";
$.each(data, function() {
var tbl_row = "";
$.each(this, function(k , v) {
tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
})
tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
})
return tbl_body;
}
function searchOptions(){
var opts = [];
$checkboxes.each(function(){
if(this.checked){
opts.push(this.name);
}
});
return opts;
}
function updateSearch(opts){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "getProfiles.php",
dataType : 'json',
cache: false,
data: {filterOpts: opts},
success: function(records){
$('#profiles tbody').html(makeTable(records));
}
});
}
var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
var opts = searchOptions();
updateSearch(opts);
});
updateSearch();
```

So every row should have it's own `<a>` tag which in PHP would be `echo '<a class="viewProfile" href="user.php?id=' . $row['ID']. '">';`

I manged to get the `<a>` on every row with `"<td><a href='user.php?id=<?php $row['ID'] ?>'>"+v+"</a></td>";` but i still need the ID

So, how do i get the ID from MySQL into the script?

Comment: In your while loop, you need to create an associate array for you results so you can easily decode the set in javascript. Example. $results[] = array('id') => $row['id']); echo json_encode($results). Then in your JQuery you can get the individual elements in the array. I presume you're familiar with Ajax responses with jquery

Comment: You can use ajax call to your php page,  passed as the "data" element. Then, the echoed json object will be stored as a javascript array in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment, something like this:

```
$.ajax({                                      
    url: 'phppage.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {   
          var json = JSON.parse(data);
          //do something with json object (extract data etc)
    } 
});
```

Comment: I do get all the needed data from the MySQL statement to the php page, so that part is fine. I just need to figure out how to organize it. The javascript organize it as it's stored in the database. I need to get the primary key into the link around every tabel row, so they work as a link